# Hello hello prolog and weka integration

Tags: java, prolog, weka, ffi, swi-prolog

I need the source code of Prolog which is used to connect with  Weka and is able to predict using Weka algorithm in windows environment. I tried to connect via Java but I can't connect and predict using Java with Prolog.

Answer (score 2):

I have connected prolog to weka, by outputting a csv file for my data, then calling weka on the csv file from prolog and reading the output of weka back into a term.

Comment: brief me the description step by step please.